# How to grant permission to create objects but only read data from objects not created by the user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a user role that can create all kind of objects but has only read permissions on objects not created by the user. Objects the user creates should be also owned by the user.

Answer (score 2):

The role needs to own a schema, and have only SELECT permissions on other schemas or on the database.  That way the role will own all the objects in its schema, and have no permissions to create objects in other schemas, or perform any operation other than SELECT.  eg

```
create role FooGroup
grant select to FooGroup --on the whole database
--the create rights are database-wide but 
--but can only be used in a schema the user controls
grant create table to FooGroup
grant create view to FooGroup
grant create proc to FooGroup
grant create function to FooGroup
go
create schema Foo authorization FooGroup
go

create user Fred without login
alter role FooGroup add member Fred

create table dbo.NonFooTable(id int)
go
execute as user='Fred'
  create table Foo.FooTable(id int);  --works
  select * from dbo.NonFooTable --works
revert

execute as user='Fred'
  create table Dbo.FooTable(id int);  --fails
go
  delete  from dbo.NonFooTable --fails
revert
```

It's critically important that FooGroup is the *owner* of the Foo schema, and isn't merely granted ALTER to a schema owned by another user.  In that case Fred could create a stored proc owned by the schema owner, and gain elevated privileges through ownership chains to other objects owned by the schema owner.

Comment: So I need a different schema for each user?

Comment: You can have multiple users in the role if you ant them to share the schema.  But if you want to keep them separate then aerate a schema per user.